# TinyMCE past image from MS Word

Tags: ms-word, copy, tinymce, paste

I need to copy word text with image to my server through copy - paste function. For that purpose, I choose TinyMCE editor.

The editor works fine, when inserting from word just text. It also works fine, when inserting from word just picture (the picture shows in TinyMCE textarea).

However, when I copy paste word text together with image, only the text shows in textarea.

Is there any way around how to solve this issue?

Next problem is, is there a plugin for TinyMCE that would get the link to the image from TinyMCE textarea, when pasting, and save the image on server?

Comment: I have the same problem now, is there any solution? using paste-plugin itself doesn't seem to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [the tinymce paste plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste) - this should be able to handle it.